# Pattern in a set of words and group them

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, correlation

I need to find how related multiple words are to each other in a set of 5000 samples.

Sample:-

1. mango, guava, litchi, apple
2. mango, guava, litchi, orange
3. mango, guava, pineapple, grape
4. pen, pencil, book, copy, notebook
5. pen, pencil, book, copy, scale

We see that 1 and 2 are very close to each other. 3 is almost close to 1 and 2. also we have 4 and 5 very close to each other.

What approach and technique we can use to check this correlation ?

Thanks in advance !

Revision : Need help in grouping as well , like group A consisting of line 1, 2, 3 and group B containing 4 and 5. ?

Comment: Maybe the occurrence of each line's words in the others ?

Comment: The problem is to define *close* - as a human being we would very easily separate fruits from electronic devices but you'll need to teach these to machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to tackle this problem. I transform each list to document-term matrix using scikit-learn. Then compute cosine similarity matrix between each rows using `scipy.spacial.distance`.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from scipy.spatial import distance

count_vect = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: x.split(', '))

ls = ['mango, guava, litchi, apple', 
      'mango, guava, litchi, orange',
      'mango, guava, pineapple, grape',
      'pen, pencil, book, copy, notebook',
      'pen, pencil, book, copy, scale']

X = count_vect.fit_transform(ls).toarray()
D = distance.cdist(X, X, metric='cosine')
```

Output is distance matrix between each row. It looks like following:

```
[[ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  1.  ,  1.  ],
 [ 0.25,  0.  ,  0.5 ,  1.  ,  1.  ],
 [ 0.5 ,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ],
 [ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  0.  ,  0.2 ],
 [ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  0.2 ,  0.  ]])
```

For example `D[0, 1]` means that row 1 is close to row 2 because the distance between two row is small. Also, you can see that `D[3, 4]` is small which means row 4 is close to row 5.

**note** you can also consider using `distance.pdist(X, metric='cosine')` which give lower diagonal of the matrix only because lower and upper diagonal are equal.

**Grouping documents**

To be more fancy, you can cluster each rows together with calculated distance matrix using hierarchical clustering.

```
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

D = distance.pdist(X, metric='cosine')
Z = hierarchy.linkage(D, metric='euclidean')
partition = hcluster.fcluster(Z, t=0.8, criterion='distance') # [2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

which means document 1,2,3 are grouped together in group 2 and 4,5 are grouped together in group 1. If you plot the dendrogram, you can see how each rows get clustered together

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hierarchy.dendrogram(Z, above_threshold_color='#bcbddc',
                     orientation='top')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, or maybe another idea of a new start to solve your question:

```
import re
from itertools import chain

a = ['mango, guava, litchi, apple', 
      'mango, guava, litchi, orange',
      'mango, guava, pineapple, grape',
      'pen, pencil, book, copy, notebook',
      'pen, pencil, book, copy, scale']

def get_words(lst):
    return [re.findall(r'[\w]+', k) for k in a]

def get_percent(lst):
    groupped_valid_dict = {}
    for k in range(len(lst)):
        sub = []
        for j in range(k+1, len(lst)):
            s = sum([1 if m == n else 0 for m, n in zip(lst[k], lst[j])])
            #percent = (1 - float(len(lst[k]) - s)/len(lst[k])) * 100
            #fmt = '%.2f%%' % percent
            #print 'Words of lines: %d and %d are %s close' %(k+1, j+1, fmt)
            if s > 0:
                sub.append("Line{}".format(j+1))
        if sub:
            groupped_valid_dict["Line{}".format(k+1)] = sub
    return groupped_valid_dict


lst = get_words(a)
lines  = get_percent(lst)
groups = [[k] + lines[k] for k in lines if k not in chain.from_iterable(lines.values())]
groups.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

for k, v in enumerate(groups, 1):
    print "Group%d" %k, v
```

Output:

```
Group1 ['Line1', 'Line2', 'Line3']
Group2 ['Line4', 'Line5']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , Can you also help in grouping them like group A with consisting of line 1, 2, 3 and group B containing 4 and 5. ?

Comment: Welcome and happy coding :-)